# Why do CDs/DVDs store a bit as the transition from one pit to another, rather than just the pit?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

In a CD or DVD, the data is stored in pits on the surface of the disk. However, rather than each pit corresponding to a bit, the transition from pit to no-pit or vice versa, or lack of, is used to store information.

However, does this have any advantages over each pit corresponding to one bit? I can't seem to find anything about it online.

I suspect it may have to do with writing to the disk, or perhaps with reducing the damage caused by scratches on the disk, but I haven't read anything that has any reasoning for why.

Comment: I believe you should start at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_recovery, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_Manchester_encoding – the same issues apply both to digital storage and digital transmission.

Comment: (The one that is directly used by HDDs and CDs is probably https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_limited)

Comment: Some system is needed to correct for small changes in how fast the disk spins.    This can be thought of a clock recovery problem.